# How to create a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to use a PivotTable finish my makro to automate a report.
I have searched for many different ways and solutions but noone have worked so far.

Here is my attempt using the macro recorder usually I avoid it but I couldn't on this one:

```
 Cells.Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "1!R1C1:R1048576C13", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Tabelle2!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Tabelle2").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PlatzID/Gerät")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Tagabfluss"), "Anzahl von Tagabfluss", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Anzahl von Tagabfluss" _
        )
        .Caption = "Summe von Tagabfluss"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    Range("E34").Select
```

I recorded it with the macro recorder but playing it doesnt work I get the error:

> Runtime Error 5 Invalid Procedure call or argument

This might be caused when I use the wrong `xlPivotTableVersion` but I checked and the one I use is matching.

Here is the one I made from a tutorial but I can't figure out what is causing errors:

```
    'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long

    'Declare Variables
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
    Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("1")

    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="PivotTable2")


    'Insert Blank Pivot Table
    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
    (TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(, 1), TableName:="PivotTable2")


    'Insert Row Fields
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("PlatzID/Gerät")
   .Orientation = xlRowField
    Position = 1
    End With

   ' With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month")
    '.Orientation = xlRowField
   ' .Position = 2
   ' End With

    'Insert Column Fields
   ' With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Zone")
   ' .Orientation = xlColumnField
   ' .Position = 1
   ' End With

    'Insert Data Field
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Tagesabfluss")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Name = "Revenue "
    End With


    'With pt
        'With .PivotFields("PlatzID/Gerät")
            '.Orientation = xlRowField
            '.Position = 1
     'End With
        '.AddDataField .PivotFields("Tagabfluss"), "Summe von Tagabfluss", xlSum
    'End With
```

This code is now mostly a big mess because I tried out many different things I thought might work. The problem is it doesnt do anything except for create the new sheet.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you removed the line `On Error Resume Next`.  This is preventing you from catching errors and debugging.

Comment: You are missing a row indicator on your `Table Destination` and missing a period in front of `Position` on your row field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it says Runtime Error 5 Types mismatch

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
    TableName:="PivotTable2")

Comment: @Cedric Why are you trying to `Set` a `PivotCache` object to a `PivotTable`?  Try just `Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address(True,True,xlR1C1,True))`

Comment: You followed the tutorial exactly to that point.  I would look at your source data in `Worksheet("1")`.  Assuming that is the name and not an index.  If your data does not start in `A1` and if it is not laid out in a manner that would allow for pivot, you will get errors as well.  Tutorial https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/

Comment: no the sheets name is 1 and it starts a1 and doesnt have any special layout or anything

Comment: I used your suggestion and its finally creating the pivot table and the first data gets put in the right place aswell now im getting an error here:    With `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Tagesabfluss")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    End With` It says runtime error 1004 the property pivot fields cant be matched with the pivot table